# Distil blocking selenium because of cookies/javascript?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping a web and since a few days I keep getting this error:

```
Oh no!
Lamentablemente, no hemos podido identificar tu navegador. 

Por favor, comprueba que JavaScript y cookies no están bloqueadas para esta 
página y vuelve a intentarlo.
```

It mainly says that the browser could not be identified and that I have to check Javascript and cookies.

To my knowledge, Selenium cookies and JS is enabled by default so it seems a problem with the browser id. This error does not seem to appear when using Firefox but then the scraping fails in other places so I am tied to Chrome.

Is there a way to tell Chrome to identify itself somehow to make it work?

Comment: have you solved this? im getting this error as well, i read somewhere it might have to do with user-agent